# Laravel save nested model hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have 3 models

```
Event has many Shifts

Shift belongs to Event

Shift has many ShiftWorkers

ShiftWorker belongs to Shift
```

when i get to save all models at once through html form with this store method in controller:

```
public function store(EventsForm $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());

    // save event
    $event = Auth::user()->events()->create($request->all());

    $total_shifts = count($request->shift_start);

    $shifts = [];

    for ($s = 0; $s <= $total_shifts-1; $s++ ) {
        array_push($shifts, new Shift(['shift_start' => $request->shift_start[$s], 'shift_end' => $request->shift_end[$s]]));
    }

    // save shifts
    $event->shifts()->saveMany($shifts);

    $workers = [];

    for ($w = 0; $w <= $total_shifts-1; $w++ ) {

        array_push($workers, new ShiftWorker(['quantity' => $request->quantity[$w], 'hour_wage' => $request->hour_wage[$w]]));

    }

    // save workers
    $event->shifts()->shift_workers()->saveMany($workers);
```

i get this error

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::shift_workers()

How can i save my third Model (ShiftWorker) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each shift has a `hasMany`, so you can't call `shift_workers()` on a collection.

You've to loop, like below:

```
foreach ($event->shifts as $shift) {
    $shift->shift_workers()->saveMany($workers);
}
```

Comment: I see, now i know what my problem is, but now it is even harder to solve this....i don't have the same number of shiftworkers in every shift....how can i save the shiftworker to his shift....which loop to use? for example if first shift has one shiftworker and second shift has 2....

Comment: That's another question, I suppose. You should determine your shift workers inside of the loop. Please mark the right answer above.